How to Swap pages in PySide6?
QStackedLayout is something brought to me by searching for ways to implement a page-switch function for PySide app. I am having a hard time figuring out the best way to explain, and therefore search for, how to swap pages.
I am an absolute beginner in GUI apps and PySide (or QT for Python) and I am currently trying to make the app have more than one “window”(?). So far the lecturer has shown us widgets and windows, so I thought to create a SettingsWindow class and then when the user clicks on settings, use some operation to “swap” the main sprawl to the settings.
“Swap” in quotes as I don’t know the best practice. I have found the above link to a stacked layout, or stacked widget, as other users have warned against swapping windows in the way I described, as it will destroy the old window.
However, the docs mention that there is no way to intrinsically swap the layouts/widgets, and that usually they are implemented as a ComboBox or ListWidget, and therefore are implemented as drop downs. Is there a way to do this without a drop-down? Am I referring to the right terms?

Your question is not clear, could you explain what you are looking for? Also, have you tried any examples with QStackedLayout or QStackedWidget so you can tell us what you don't like or what you hope to get.

I agree with what noted above: your question is unclear. Nonetheless: 1. "swapping windows" doesn't intrinsically destroy old ones, it depends on how they're created and how their references are kept; 2. the purpose of QStackedLayout (and the convenience QStackedWidget, which fundamentally is a QWidget with a QStackedLayout implicitly set on it) is to allow swapping contained widgets, including widgets that just act as containers for layouts; 3. QComboBox/QListWidget may be indirectly used to control stacked widgets/layouts, but they are just one (and not strictly related) way to do it.

@eyllanesc Apologies, my question was sort of two parts and I should have waited until the morning to post with my laptop.
I wanted to know what the best way to describe the behaviour of the app I was after, which I think is "pages" to refer to different sections. In web-apps I would call these pages so that makes sense.

A paged interface doesn't seem appropriate at all. The settings belong in a separate modal dialog. The main window should not be hidden. Almost all desktop applications work in this way. Don't confuse your users by trying to reinvent the wheel. As a beginner, it's best to keep things simple - you will make faster progress that way, and it will be easier to find helpful examples/documentation that relate to what you are trying to achieve.

You can use a QStackedWidget, add widgets (as pages) to it with addWidget(), and navigate between them with setCurrentIndex().

And using this I wouldn't need to implement a QComboBox or QListWidget? I could use the signal from a button and connect it to the slot of QStackedWidget? (I am not familiar with the right phrasing)

No need for QComboBox or QListWidget. Use whatever you like to send an int to the setCurrentIndex() and you will see that page.
